# Bad state: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized. Make sure to call [FirebaseApp()] or [FirebaseApp.withOptions()] first

Tags: firebase, flutter

I was making the Flash Chat by Flutter Bootcamp and after authenticating and everything done , I just restarted the application . As soon as I click on register button I could see this error
Bad state: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized. Make sure to call [FirebaseApp()] or [FirebaseApp.withOptions()] first.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmMpp.jpg)
Please Solve this problem

Comment: please click on that link to see the image

Comment: Please include errors as Text in the actual question. Over time, links can break and if it does, it would invalidate the question.

Comment: I think it's a setup issue just make sure that all your setup is correctly configured.